# How to determine if a client can call an api endpoint using IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, identityserver4

I have api endpoints in a Web API where I protect access to their endpoints using IdentityServer4 in ASPNET Core 2.0. The api has multiple ApiScopes like "can_read" and "can_write". I want to know how can I determine if a client calling the endpoint can call the endpoint by determining if the Access Token sent in the Authorization Header has that scope?

Comment: the answer is pretty much in the question... what have you tried so far?

Comment: I created a token retriever service to retrieve a token from a query string or header to retrieve the access token `var token = TokenRetrieverService.FromHeaderAndQueryString(HttpContext.Request);
                if(token == null)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Could not retrieve an access token");
                }` Now I dont know how to use the access token to determine if it has a specific api scope

Comment: so you have your own answer then, surely?

Comment: I dont know how to use the access token to determine if it has a specific api scope

Comment: have you tried google?

Comment: Yes I have with  no success

Comment: Thanks got an answer to it I will post an answer to it

Answer (score 1):

You can use JwtSecurityTokenHandler class to decode the Base64Encoded Access Token. Then you can inspect the contents of the token and determine if it contains the claims you are expecting.